# Same Width to DropDownList and TexBox element

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

I have a table into which there are DropDownList and TexBox elements.
I'm in trouble with the "width" of them..
The problem is that when I go to resize the browser's page they change the width in different way even though they have the same settings.

These are the two cells on the first row of the table (a simple label and a DropDownList):

```
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, Parking %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroup" runat="server" Height="26px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, null, this.value, null, null, null, null, null);"
         TabIndex="2" Width="98%"> 
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
```

These are other two cells with the TexBox and his label, placed into the second row of the table:

```
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
      <asp:Label ID="lblFrom" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, From %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
      <div style="z-index: 1; width: 92%;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateStart" runat="server" autocomplete="off" Height="15px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(this.value, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);"
            Style="z-index: 1" TabIndex="4" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalDateStart" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDateStart">
        </cc1:CalendarExtender>
      </div>
    </td>
```

My question is if there is a way to controll the width of DropDownList and TexBox to make sure that their width is always equal to each other.

PS: to the narrowing of the page, the DropDownList become shorter than TexBox

EDIT: the complete code of the table:

```
<table id="tblFilter" style="width: 100%; background-color: White;">
  <tr>
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
      <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, Parking %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
      <div style="z-index: 1; width: 100%;">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroup" runat="server" Height="26px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, null, this.value, null, null, null, null, null);"
            TabIndex="2" Width="99%"> 
        </asp:DropDownList> <!-- Width="98%" rimuover il <div> -->
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px;">
    </td>
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblParkmeter" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, Parkmeter %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParkmeter" runat="server" Height="26px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, null, null, null, this.value, null, null, null);"
             TabIndex="3" Width="98%">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px;">
    </td>
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblTariff" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" 
             Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, DescRate %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRate" runat="server" Height="26px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, null, null, null, null, null, this.value, null);"
             TabIndex="3" Width="98%">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px; visibility:hidden">
        <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, City %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="visibility:hidden; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" Height="26px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, null, null, this.value, null, null, null, null);"
             TabIndex="1" Width="98%">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblFrom" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, From %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
        <div style="z-index: 1; width: 92%;">
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateStart" runat="server" autocomplete="off" Height="15px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(this.value, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);"
                Style="z-index: 1" TabIndex="4" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
           <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalDateStart" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDateStart">
           </cc1:CalendarExtender>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px;">
    </td>
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, To %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
        <div style="z-index: 1; width: 92%;">
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateEnd" runat="server" autocomplete="off" Height="15px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, this.value, null, null, null, null, null, null);"
                Style="z-index: 1" TabIndex="5" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
           <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalDateEnd" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDateEnd">
           </cc1:CalendarExtender>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px;">
    </td>
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" 
            Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, Type %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
        <asp:DropDownList Width="98%" ID="ddlLabel" runat="server" Height="26px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, null, null, null, null, this.value, null, null);"
            TabIndex="6">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px;">
    </td>
    <td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 200px;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblNumCard" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" 
             Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, Tessera %>"></asp:Label>:
    </td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; width: 200px;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumCard" runat="server" Height="15px" onkeyup="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, this.value);"
             TabIndex="7" Width="92%" MaxLength="9"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px;">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your "td" width in percentage not in pixels. Pixels will fix the width of your "td" and will not re-size itself when your browser window re-sizes.

```
<td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5" Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, Parking %>"></asp:Label>:
</td>
<td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 5px; width: 100%;">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroup" runat="server" Height="26px" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, null, this.value, null, null, null, null, null);"
     TabIndex="2" Width="98%"> 
  </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

Thanks.

Comment: the problem isn't that. The table is resizing but the problem is the inside elements. The DropDownList and the TexBox don't resize in the same way (the DropDownList result shorter)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootstrap? Remove the styles from each td other than width, remove the height and width from the dropdownlist and add 'form-control' to the CssClass in both controls. It should set the width correctly - see below:

```
<td class="tabtitle_filtri" style="width: 100px;">
<asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" CssClass="marginleft5 form-control" Text="<%$ Resources:FORMS, Parking %>"></asp:Label>:
</td>
<td style="width: 100%;">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroup" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" onchange="javascript: return loadTicketsList(null, null, this.value, null, null, null, null, null);"
 TabIndex="2"> 
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>`
```

Comment: Thanx Chris for your answare.
I don't use the Boostrap. i don't have the CcClass form-control